# how to Ping ip address with parameter(-n,-t etc) in c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I am developing a windows form application. I have a requirement, need ping the system ip address with parameters. like ping IP Address -n 1.

I am Unable to pass the parameter using ping.send function.

Any one can help me.

Answer (score 1):

use `Ping` class. This provides a more organized approach

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingTest
{
    public class PingExample
    {
        // args[0] can be an IPaddress or host name. 
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions ();

            // Use the default Ttl value which is 128, 
            // but change the fragmentation behavior.
            options.DontFragment = true;

            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted. 
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);
            int timeout = 120;
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (args[0], timeout, buffer, options);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
                Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
                Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
                Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
                Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spam a cmd process and get its output.

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -i 10");
process.StandardInput.Close();
string answer = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close()
Console.WriteLine(answer);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Also need to display Buffer ,Round trip time, Ttl. please provide this functionality using above code.

Comment: You can use all cmd ping flags to get this information: TTL (-i). Round trip time is also shown at the end of answer. Example: Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds: Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 1ms

Comment: Ok. I added the TTL flag for 10 hops into the code above

Comment: The -i flag is for setting the hop count for you packet, that you send to the IP-address. The TTL of the answer is shown per default in ping answers, that you get too. To read them all you can parse the answer for keywords as "TTL", etc, or if you write an application for multilingual OSs use regex. But I think, that the keywords are uniform for all languages